# segmentation fault while running executable android ndk module

Tags: java, android, c++, unit-testing, android-ndk

I have java application, where I use C++ code. All c++ code is compiled to .so file.
I have to write unit tests for native part of the project. 
I wrote such unit test:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gtest-all.cc>
#include <myTestedFile.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>    

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    return 0;
}

TEST(MyTest, Test1)
{
    jclass jc;
    int k = jni_return_five((JNIEnv*)0, jc);
    ASSERT_EQ(k,5);
}
```

there is file myTestedFile.cpp

```
#include "myTestedFile.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL jni_return_five(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
        jclass commonClass = env->FindClass(
"com/android/appportal/common/Myclass");
    return 5;
}
```

I start this test with such way

```
adb push libs/armeabi-v7a/myTest /data/local/tmp
adb push libs/armeabi-v7a/myLibrary.so /data/local/tmp
adb shel "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/tmp data/local/tmp/myTest"
```

After this I have output

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyTest
[ RUN      ] MyTest.Test1
Segmentation fault
```

Test is passed succesfully, if I dont get references to java classes in the jni code. Can anyone help me with this error?

There is logcat of the crash

```
F/libc    (10105): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 10105 (myLibrary)
I/DEBUG   (  113): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  113): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/espresso10rfxx/espresso10rf:4.0.3/IML74K/P5100XWALE2:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  113): Revision: '10'
I/DEBUG   (  113): pid: 10105, tid: 10105, name: myLibrary  >>> /data/local/tmp/myTest <<<
I/DEBUG   (  113): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
W/NativeCrashListener(  399): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 10105

I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268c8  004e1de8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268cc  be826a6c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268d0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268d4  4021fdb4  /data/local/tmp/libgnustl_shared.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+8)
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268d8  004e2610  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268dc  0000bc70  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268e0  402a22f0  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268e4  004e1e44  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268e8  00039df8  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268ec  be826918  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268f0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268f4  be82690c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268f8  e3a070ad  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be8268fc  ef9000ad  
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #00  be826900  000384c4  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826904  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826908  be826924  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be82690c  0002d9b4  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #01  be826910  004e1ee0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826914  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826918  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be82691c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826920  be82695c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826924  0001df80  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):     #02  be826928  be826944  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be82692c  0001f040  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826930  000105cc  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826934  004e2548  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826938  004e1ee0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be82693c  00039df8  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826940  be826954  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826944  00010620  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826948  be826954  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be82694c  004e1ee0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826950  be82695c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826954  004e2568  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826958  be826974  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be82695c  00010e30  /data/local/tmp/myTest
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826960  be82696c  [stack]
I/DEBUG   (  113):          be826964  004e2548  [heap]
```

Comment: the `logcat` of the crash would provide some additional information.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito
I added logcat to the question

Comment: The logcat should also include the callstack of the crash.

Comment: It looks like you are passing a null argument with `jni_return_five((JNIEnv*)0, jc);` and then dereferencing that argument by calling the `FindClass()` method on it.

Comment: @rhashimoto Yes, you are right.
I solved this problem with creating of wrapper for JNIEnv class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with creating of wrapper for JNIEnv class.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?